# Ayuda con query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un query que me da el sIguiente resultado:

consulta

```sql
select F.Semana, F.Cantidad 
FROM TPersonas as P 
left join TFacturas F ON P.Codigo=F.Codigo 
where P.Codigo= 00138
```

tablas

```
TPersonas
Codigo int (PK)
Nombre varchar

TFacturas
id int (PK)
Codigo int
Semana int
Cantidad int
```

resultado

```
semana  cantidad
27  NULL
28  NULL
29  NULL
30  3434
31  5
32  454
33  565
34  76898
35  978
36  78
37  NULL
38  67
39  656
40  987
41  4
42  NULL
43  6
44  876
45  NULL
46  565
47  34
48  NULL
49  33
50  545
51  NULL
52  545
1   23
2   4343
3   545
4   766
5   98
6   980
7   800
8   787
9   34
10  76
11  337
12  454
13  NULL
14  NULL
15  87
16  900
17  76
18  NULL
19  67
20  675
21  45
22  45
23  344
24  2234
25  22
26  1233
```

Pero sucede que lo necesito asi:

```
semana  cantidad  semana  cantidad
======= ========  ======= ========
27      NULL      1       23
28      NULL      2       4343
29      NULL      3       545
30      3434      4       766
31      5         5       98
32      454       6       980
33      565       7       800
34      76898     8       787
35      978       9       34
36      78        10      76
37      NULL      11      337
38      67        12      454
39      656       13      NULL
40      987       14      NULL
41      4         15      87
42      NULL      16      900
43      6         17      76
44      876       18      NULL
45      NULL      19      67
46      565       20      675
47      34        21      45
48      NULL      22      45
49      33        23      344
50      545       24      2234
51      NULL      25      22
52      545       26      1233
```

Uso SQL server 2014, y quería saber si existe alguna manera de lograr este acomodo.
Gracias.

Comment: por favor edita y agrega la consulta, sino la comunidad no sabrá como es que consigues el primer resultado, además también anexa la estructura de la tabla

Comment: básicamente tendrías que agregar los campos que necesitas y en el orden que los quieres en tu **select**, si por ejemplo pides mostrar F.Semana, F.Cantidad, no te va a traer otros, si quieres traer otro campo más (este es un ejemplo), seria **select F.Semana, F.Cantidad, F.fecha From...**. Tú los ordenas a tu gusto

Comment: ¿qué son las columnas `c..` y `s..`?

Comment: @jachguate significa cantidad y semana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes construir un CTE que te devuelva la *estadística* de facturas por semana. Y hacer un *join* entre este mismo CTE dos veces, uno para obtener las semanas de la 27 a la 52 , y otro para obtener las semanas de la 1 a la 26.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo un hipotético *CTE* llamado `FacturasPorSemana`, algo como:

```sql
select   S1.Semana
       , F1.Cantidad
       , S2.Semana 
       , F2.Cantidad
  from Semana S1
       left join FacturasPorSemana F1 on F1.Semana = S1.Semana
       inner join Semana S2 
                  left join FacturasPorSemana F2 on F2.Semana = S2.Semana
               on S2.Semana = S1.Semana % 27 + 1
 where S1.Semana >= 27
```

Para comprobarlo, he partido de la definición de tablas que has dado y he realizado, primero, una *vista al vuelo* que me de las semanas de la 1 a la 52, luego, el ya mencionado CTE `FacturasPorSemana` que me va a dar la estadística por semana del cliente que me interesa, y finalmente, con esta he realizado la consulta que ya te puse arriba. El script completo sería:

```sql
with
  X1(n) as (select null union all select null)
, X2(n) as (select null from X1 a cross join X1 b)
, X4(n) as (select null from X2 a cross join X2 b)
, X8(n) as (select null from X4 a cross join X4 b)
, Num(n) as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by n) from X8)
, Semana as (select n as Semana from Num where n <= 52)
, 
TPersonas as (
select 138 Codigo, 'X' Nombre
union all select 139, 'Y'
)
,
TFacturas as (
          select 138 Codigo, 23 Cantidad, 1 Semana
union all select 138, 4343, 2
union all select 138, 545, 3
union all select 138, 766, 4
union all select 138, 98, 5
union all select 138, 980, 6
union all select 138, 800, 7
union all select 138, 787, 8
union all select 138, 34, 9
union all select 138, 76, 10
union all select 138, 337, 11
union all select 138, 454, 12
union all select 138, 87, 15
union all select 138, 900, 16
union all select 138, 76, 17
union all select 138, 67, 19
union all select 138, 675, 20
union all select 138, 45, 21
union all select 138, 45, 22
union all select 138, 344, 23
union all select 138, 2234, 24
union all select 138, 22, 25
union all select 138, 1233, 26
union all select 138, 3434, 30
union all select 138, 5, 31
union all select 138, 454, 32 
union all select 138, 565, 33
union all select 138, 76898, 34
union all select 138, 978, 35
union all select 138, 78, 36
union all select 138, 67, 38
union all select 138, 656, 39
union all select 138, 987, 40
union all select 138, 4, 41
union all select 138, 6, 43
union all select 138, 876, 44
union all select 138, 565, 46
union all select 138, 34, 47
union all select 138, 33, 49
union all select 138, 545, 50
union all select 138, 545, 52
)
,
FacturasPorSemana as (
select F.Semana, SUM(F.Cantidad) Cantidad
  from TFacturas F 
       inner join TPersonas P on P.Codigo = F.Codigo               
 where P.Codigo = 138
group by F.Semana
)
select   S1.Semana
       , F1.Cantidad
       , S2.Semana 
       , F2.Cantidad
  from Semana S1
       left join FacturasPorSemana F1 on F1.Semana = S1.Semana
       inner join Semana S2 
                  left join FacturasPorSemana F2 on F2.Semana = S2.Semana
               on S2.Semana = S1.Semana % 27 + 1
 where S1.Semana >= 27
```

Que me arroja como resultado:

```
Semana               Cantidad    Semana               Cantidad
-------------------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
27                   NULL        1                    23
28                   NULL        2                    4343
29                   NULL        3                    545
30                   3434        4                    766
31                   5           5                    98
32                   454         6                    980
33                   565         7                    800
34                   76898       8                    787
35                   978         9                    34
36                   78          10                   76
37                   NULL        11                   337
38                   67          12                   454
39                   656         13                   NULL
40                   987         14                   NULL
41                   4           15                   87
42                   NULL        16                   900
43                   6           17                   76
44                   876         18                   NULL
45                   NULL        19                   67
46                   565         20                   675
47                   34          21                   45
48                   NULL        22                   45
49                   33          23                   344
50                   545         24                   2234
51                   NULL        25                   22
52                   545         26                   1233

(26 rows affected)
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Esta query la paso a un gridview pero me marca este error : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' no contiene una propiedad con el nombre "Codigo"

Comment: No parece algo relacionado al query o al SQL en si, ¿seguro que tu código no referencia ninguna propiedad llamada _"Codigo"_ en los bindings?